# Query data based on pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a database design which essentially takes the following form (I have removed a lot of fields as they are not really needed for demonstration purposes).  I have a users table

```
users
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | name          | email           | 
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | ProjectA      | Something       |    
+----+---------------+-----------------+
```

A user can have many projects

```
projects
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | name          | description     | user_id         |
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | ProjectA      | Something       | 1               | 
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

So that is straight forward enough and very easy to query.  If I want all projects for the logged in user I can do

```
$loggedInUser = Auth::user()->getFirstName() . ' '  . Auth::user()->getLastName();
$loggedInUserId = User::where('userName', '=', $loggedInUser)->first();

$projectss = Project::all()->where('user_id', $loggedInUserId);
```

This is where things get a little more tricky.  I have a pivot table for a users groups.  It is essentially this

```
users_user_groups
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | user_id       | group_id        | 
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1             | 2               |    
+----+---------------+-----------------+
```

I then have a user_groups table

```
user_groups
+----+---------------+
| id | group_name    |             
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Group A       | 
+----+---------------+
```

If I want to find what groups a user is a part of I can do

```
$userGroups = Auth::user()->getGroups();
```

My question is this.  Above, I demonstrate how I can get all projects for a user.  Now I know there is a user_group called Group A.  What I essentially want to do is get all projects where the user is apart of Group A.  So if 5 users create a project and they are all in Group A, then I should be returned 5 projects.

How would I go about doing something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can get user id using simply `Auth::user()->id`

Assuming you are trying to get all the projects that belongs to users of a  group You can do this.

```
$group = Group::with('users.projects')->find(1);
```

Group model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

User Model

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}
```

Of course you would have to make the appropriate relation methods depending on the forign/primary keys you used.